# React change html element title to that of the result returned by function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

So essentially I have some existing elements, and it works obviously, but I want a dynamic name:

```
<MenuItem primaryText='Foo Name'/>
```

But how can I make it so that this works, where the text of the element can change:

```
<MenuItem primaryText={this.foo}/>
```

Basically the function foo returns one of two strings, based on the component state. e.g:

```
foo() {
  if (this.state.show === true) {
    return 'Hide';
  } else {
    return 'Show';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the returned value of a function, you need to invoke it.
In this case - `this.foo()`:

```
<MenuItem primaryText={this.foo()}/>
```